# OsmAnd: How to update a map?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmand

I am an avid user of OsmAnd. Some of the maps I have are now becoming a bit outdated - shops that changed name, paths that no longer exist, new paths that are not yet marked.

How can I update a map that I already have on my system?

Comment: 2 ways : once is to use the tools dedicate for that but you have only 10 update available with the free version. Second : you download files from osmand ftp server http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/ and put them on your file system where osmand is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, the OsmAnd~ (mind the "~") version available from **F-Droid** (https://www.f-droid.org) doesn't include the 10-map download limit : https://f-droid.org/fr/packages/net.osmand.plus/

You can simply download/update your maps from within the app :

1. Start OsmAnd Tap the "Menu" icon.
2. Tap "Download maps".
3. Pick the regions of your liking. You can also swipe the the "Update" tab to update already-present maps.

You'll need an Internet connexion for that. Also, be wary that maps can easily be hundreds of MiB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) in size.

Comment: Could you please explain how to update a map from the application?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa : do you mean *modifying* the map from within the application ? You can add/modify POIs (point of interest) by selecting one on the map, then tapping "Actions/Create a POI", but it's more easily done by login on https://www.openstreetmap.org/ and using the browser-based tool. Other tools and apps exist, though, but I have little to no experience with them. Try https://search.f-droid.org/?q=openstreetmap for Vespucci, or StreetComplete, for instance.
EDIT : J.R's answer seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer are good when it's only your version of the map (the one on your device) that's outdated.

When even the newest map available for download are also outdated you should update the original OSM mapdata (see here [Contribute_map_data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contribute_map_data) or here for [doing it with OsmAnd](https://osmand.net/features/osm-editing-plugin))

Then you'll have to wait till your modifications are integrated in the next version of the downloadable OsmAnd map (or you could create your own map : [OsmAndMapCreator](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmAndMapCreator))